# Android - MediaController leaking on activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I am using MediaPlayer and MediaController objects to stream audio.  When closing the activity  I am getting a window leaked exception.

I have the following in my activity which doesn't help at all.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();

}
```

I get the following stack trace:

> 01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286): Activity
>   co.uk.ing_simmons.aberdeensoundsites.RecordingDetails has leaked
>   window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4182d590
>   that was originally added here 01-24 20:11:18.317:
>   E/WindowManager(26286): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   co.uk.ing_simmons.aberdeensoundsites.RecordingDetails has leaked
>   window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4182d590
>   that was originally added here 01-24 20:11:18.317:
>   E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:418) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:294)
>   01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
>   01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
>   01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:470) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:429) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   co.uk.ing_simmons.aberdeensoundsites.RecordingDetails$2.run(RecordingDetails.java:202)
>   01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 01-24 20:11:18.317:
>   E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-24 20:11:18.317:
>   E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
>   01-24 20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 01-24
>   20:11:18.317: E/WindowManager(26286):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-24 20:11:18.325:
>   E/InputEventReceiver(26286): channel '41c81858
>   Panel:co.uk.ing_simmons.aberdeensoundsites/co.uk.ing_simmons.aberdeensoundsites.RecordingDetails
>   (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred. 
>   events=0x9

Which seems to point to line 202 which is this line:

```
mediaController.show();
```

I have been Googling this for hours now and literally everything says to put "mediaController.hide()" in the onStop method to prevent leaks.  Which clearly isn't working so any help or guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to reverse the lines

```
super.onStop();
mediaController.hide();
```

to

```
mediaController.hide();
super.onStop();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm still getting the "has leaked window" error.